# Google chart legend shrinking text

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

Here is my code:

```
var chart = [[''],['']];
chart[0][1]='Spearmint';
chart[1][1]='3.95';

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartArr);
 var options = {
     title: questions[i].getAttribute("desc"),
     is3D: true,
     width:600 //with or without this parameter
 };
 chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('questionchart_' + questions[i].getAttribute("num")));
 chart.draw(data, options);
```

It seems to be cutting off the legend text. **You only need to reference the first graph**

Here is an image:

[Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntqfn.png)

If you look closely, you'll see the legends display `Sp....`. This is inaccurate as it should display the full name of the location (`Spearmint`).

Here is my `DOM Element` its using:

```
<div id="questionchart_1" style="width:750px"></div>
```

I have no idea how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the `chartArea` needs to be adjusted according to the placement of the legend and the size of the labels that need to be displayed.
Also need to consider the size of the title, axis labels, etc...

Here, I've added a background color to help demonstrate...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  callback: drawChart
});

function drawChart() {
  var chartArr = [[''],['']];
  chartArr[0][1] = 'Spearmint';
  chartArr[1][1] = 3.95;

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartArr);
  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      backgroundColor: 'cyan',
      height: 320,
      left: 32,
      top: 40,
      width: 434
    },
    height: 400,
    legend: {
      position: 'right'
    },
    title: 'Flavors',
    width: 600
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('questionchart_0'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="questionchart_0"></div>
```